# Django redirect on error to main home page or app root

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm trying to not hardcode the url of the app in the view (really the controller) of an app.

Code looks like this:

```
event/view.py

def index(request):

  try:
    //do stuff with response
    return render(request, 'rma/service.html', response)
  except:
    return redirect("/rma")
```

In this case the app is installed on the web server under /var/www/html/rma. but in production (or anywhere else) it could be installed at any subdirectory or html/

How can I redirect to the main page because if this specific page fails the main page will display better logic of what's going on (sources missing in DB, table not imported, etc.)

i'd like to do something like:

```
return redirect(<magic>.main.index)
```

or even like:

```
return redirect(APP_ROOT)
```

All example i found is redirecting inside html (the template) rather than in code in the view.py

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your `urls.py` files for both the app in question and your project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to edit 2 files, website/urls.py, and views.py

**Inside of views.py:**

```
def handler404(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')


def handler500(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

This defines what to do when an error comes up, and the code can be changed to have custom error pages.

**Inside of urls.py:**

```
handler404 = 'my_app.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'my_app.views.handler500'
```

Replacing my_app with whatever Django app you are using (ex. polls.)

This code directs the code to the code inside of your views.py file.

Note: You will need to point other things to this view if you would like it to redirect not only on 500 and 404 errors.